# Take a screenshot of all bookmarks in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, screenshot

I have a huge list of bookmarks in google chrome saved for design inspiration. I would like to take a screenshot of all sites and save them to my computer, that way i can still keep copies of the sites as they change. So, what would be the easiest way to take a screenshot of all the sites in my bookmarks? I would prefer not having to do it manually...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies: grep, sed, webkit2png (or khtml2png)

1) Export your bookmarks from Chrome to ~/bookmarks. They'll be exported in an XML format.

2) get a list of URLs from the file (use xmlstarlet if you want something more proper than this grep hack) and pipe to webkit2png if on mac or khtml2png if on linux:

```
cat ~/bookmarks | grep -oE 'A HREF="[^"]+"' | sed -e 's/^A HREF="//' -e 's/"$//' | while read URL; do webkit2png "$URL"; done
```

Comment: +1 Now that's just plain cool. So cool, I'm wishing I could switch operating systems. Is there a version for us poor Windows users?